# Intution for the physical meaning of high energy limit of a quantum states and uniform distribution in phase spacehow of a particle

Tags: quantum-mechanics, statistical-mechanics, wavefunction, chaos-theory, semiclassical

Zeev Rudnick state in his talk [Quantum Ergodicity for the Uninitiated](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EJGuCLBCwD4) (around 12 minute 40 second mark at the last text section of the slide) that a "*a possible interpretation of the statement that 'wave functions cover phase space uniformly' is that the matrix elements converge to the classical average at $a(.,.)$ (with $a(.,.)$ being a classical observable)*. I am trying to understand/develop some intution for the physical meaning of the high energy limit and the equidistribution in phase space with respect to the more intuitive classical case situation. By this I mean the following:

Pick your favorite chaotic system. For simplicity, let us assume that it is some billiard/gas system, e.g. [Sinai billiard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamical_billiards#Lorentz_gas,_a.k.a._Sinai_billiard). Then if $\Phi$ is the (discrete) evolution equation on our system with configuration space $S$, we know that for almost all initial states $(q, p)$ and every test function $f$, $\lim_{N\to\infty}\frac{1}{N}\sum_{j=0}^{N-1}f(\Phi^j(q, p)) = \int_S fdqdp$. This is what we mean to say the system is chaotic and the orbits traver pretty much everywhere. To my knowledge in the case of the Sinai billiard we even have same convergence in physical space: $\lim_{N\to\infty}\frac{1}{N}\sum_{j=0}^{N-1}f(\tilde{\Phi}^j(q) = \int_S fdq$ (with maybe slightly altered evolution function $\tilde{\Phi}$). But in any case, in the classical system we have more or less

$$\text{Limiting time average} = \text{Space average}$$

In the case of a quantum system, we lose knowledge of the exact position and momentum of our particle and have to infer information from the probability distribution given by the wave equation solving the Schrödinger evolution equation with e.g. Dirichlet boundary conditions. For sake of clarity, let us enumerate the solutions as $\psi_1,\psi_2,\dots$ as in Rudnick's talk and denote $\psi_j(z;t)$ the $j$th solution at time $t$. Since solutions to the Schrödinger equation are standing waves, $\psi_j(z;0)$ and $\psi_j(z;t)$ give the same probability distribution. So then when we talk about "uniform distribution" w.r.t. "something" that "something" doesn't seem to be the time but rather the index the standing wave or equivalently the level of energy since $E_{\psi_j}\to\infty$.

As of writing I don't really know how to connect the high energy limit back to the classical analogue of

$$\text{Limiting time average} = \text{Space average}$$

and I don't know can you do so: The high energy limit (and hence possible equidistribution in phase space) seems to happen "immediately" in the sense that

1.) I give you some nice enough system e.g. classically chaotic billiard

2.) Instead of letting any time pass and allowing some wave to "fill" and evolve in the system you
i.) Solve the appropriate wave equation
ii.) Take the high energy limit

(**Alas my actual question**): So what does such uniform distribution in the phase space represent physically or does it represent anything? Even if we were to just look at the probability distributions $|\psi_j(z;0)|^2$ and say that #uniform distribution" here means that as $j\to\infty$, the probability of a particle being at any region in the physical space is given by

$$\frac{\text{area of region of interest}}{\text{total area}}$$

I still don't really understand how it connects to the classical case of

$$\text{Limiting time average} = \text{Space average}$$

since no time or anything which we would "intuitively" interpret as a source of evolution (e.g. time) seems to pass; we just look at the high energy limit of the system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***This is a long comment, not an answer*** to your open-ended broad question... I cannot imagine a short, pithy answer. So I'll reframe your questions (?) and suggest famous physics literature (not math: I hardly recognized any of you mathematician's speakers references!). If, instead, you wished to persist in [semiclassical wavefunctions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_ergodicity), you might consider [M V Berry (1981) "Quantizing a classically ergodic system: Sinai's billiard and the KKR method", *Ann Phys*  **131** (1) 163-216](https://doi.org/10.1098/rsta.1977.0145) .

In any case, comparing classical trajectories with wavefunctions can only lead you to unwarranted grief and confusion, striving to compare apples with oranges. So, instead, I would argue for doing these comparisons in the [phase-space formulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase-space_formulation) for QM, where you compare oranges with tangerines, as your speaker does, so to speak...

If you are happy with the intuition on time averages versus phase-space such provided by the videos there, and the well-understood quantum oscillator, all *non-ergodic systems!*; then, and *only then*, you can move on to quantum ergodicity in that language:

- [J  Hutchinson &  R  Wyatt  (1980), "Quantum ergodicity and the Wigner distribution", *Chem Phys Lett*  **72** (2) 378-384](https://doi.org/10.1016/0009-2614(80)80311-3)      ;
- [H J Korsch  &  M V Berry (1981), "Evolution of Wigner's phase-space density under a nonintegrable quantum map", *Physica D: Nonlinear Phenomena*  **3** (3) 627-636](https://doi.org/10.1016/0167-2789(81)90045-2) .

There have been mountains of followup papers and even books/reviews in the intervening forty years... If you really had gumption, you might slug through [M V Berry, (1977), "Semi-classical mechanics in phase space: a study of Wigner’s function" *Phil Trans  Roy Soc Lond* Ser A Mathematical and Physical Sciences **287**(1343) 237-271](https://www.jstor.org/stable/74926).